# Capture part of the URI and use it to do conditional rewrites in Nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I am writing a location block for a Nginx config, and it is for URIs with pattern like this: `www.mysite.com/a/b/blah/c` or `www.mysite.com/a/b/blah/c/n`.

Where `a` and `b` are fixed, `blah` may vary, `c` can be one of three fixed strings (optionA, optionB, optionC) only, and `n` is a digit starting from 0, 1, 2, and so on. In addition, `n` is valid only when `c` is equal to optionB, so that in any other case Nginx should throw a `404` immediately if there is anything after `c`.

I intend to write a location block as:

```
location ^~ /a/b/ {
    ...
}
```

The logic I want to implement inside this location: first capture `c` from a given URI, and based on its value, do one of three possible rewrites. i.e.

```
if (c = optionA) {
    rewrite ... ... break;
}

if (c = optionB) {
    rewrite ... ... break;
}

if (c = optionC) {
    rewrite ... ... break;
}
```

My questions are:

1. I have read that `if` statement should be generally avoided in location block in Nginx, but it seems like its use with `rewrite` is an exception. Will the way I use `rewrite` here cause any problem?
2. How do I capture `c` and implement the conditional rewrite logic here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use regexp, something like: www.mysite.com/(.*)/(.*)/blah/c
and $1, $2 for founded url's parts.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. But where do I do this regex? If I do at location matching level, will the resulting variables `$1`, `$2`, etc conflict with the ones resulting from the regex match for the rewrite within each `if` statement inside the location block?

Comment: just look at examples on the official site of nginx:
http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html